Meaning of ズボラ here
I am not certain with the meaning of ズボラ here:

果たして、ときメモは「美少女ゲーム」というジャンルの代名詞となります。特にマンガにも出てくる「虹野沙希」ちゃんは、後に一番人気になるキャラクターです。その理由は大ボス藤崎詩織があまりに攻略が面倒くさい一方で、沙希ちゃんは攻略が簡単でしかも自分を勇気づけてくれる優しい女の子だったからだったのです。この後、美少女ゲーの歴史は「プレイヤーのズボラ化」の歴史となっていくのですが・・・それはまた後のお話。

Does プレイヤーのズボラ化 mean "sloppification of players"? Considering the nature of the game ときメモ, players becoming ズボラ means they seek ways to experience romance in quick and easy way?

Considering the context (藤崎詩織の攻略が面倒), this プレイヤーのズボラ化 indeed likely refers to the fact that players have become less inclined to think or put effort into playing games of this genre. If I understand the history correctly, shortly after Tokimemo, simulation game mechanics disappeared entirely from many bishōjo games. Many were still technically categorized as 恋愛シミュレーション, but most of them were designed as mere visual novel games where players simply choose from a few conversational options.
